# Angular Component Template Size

Tags: angular

If I am concerned with performance, should I structure my app in Angular using fewer components with larger templates or with more components with smaller templates?

It seems as if there were more components, there would a lot more lifecycles to work through, although there would be more logic to run through with bigger templates.

Anyone have any ideas of how these two approaches would affect app performance?

Comment: If you want to be sure then do a benchmark. I prefer fewer components with smaller templates :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not focus on performance related to templates. **Always** try to structure your components/templates in the most logical way, extract smaller parts to reusable components. Its natural to have many small pieces with relatively small templates.

If you notice performance issues, typically start with investigation of how often does Angular runs the change detection and how often is re-rendering the HTML View (that's slow).

Starting with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` can help a lot, there's a perfect article here: [Angular Change Detection Explained](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)